# php / ajax REMOTE_ADDR set to IP of bogus network adapter

Tags: php, ajax

today I came a across a pretty strange behaviour of an php based application of mine.
In a certain part of the system there's an UI making use of AJAX-calls to fill list
boxes with content from the backend.

Now, the AJAX listener performs a security check on all incoming requests, making sure
that only valid client IPs get responses. The valid IP are stored in the backend too.

To get the client's IP I used plain old

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

which works out for most of the clients. Today I ran into an installation where
remote_addr contained the IP of an network adapter which was'nt that one which performed
the actual communication for my application.

Googling around agve me [Roshan's Blog entry on the topuic](http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/getting-real-ip-address-in-php.html):

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))//check ip is pass from prxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Sadly the problem persists.

Did anybody ever stumble into this sort of problem (actually I don't think that I discovered a completly new issue ^^) and has an idea for me how to fix this?

**EDIT:**

I'm on

- PHP Version 5.2.9-1
- Apache/2.2.9 (Win32)

The communication is done via a regular LAN card. Now the actuall client has several
devices more. VMNet adapters and such.

I'm wondering how a client configuration can 'disturb' a web server that much...

TIA

K

Comment: can you put in some details here regarding the adopters and the server running the application.. i mean what IPs do they hold.

Comment: so example scenario might look like this on client end: 
eth0 - 10.0.0.1 
eth1 - 10.1.1.1

then on server u have 10.1.1.2 and when the request goes through from client instead of 10.1.1.1 it shows 10.0.0.1 ?

Comment: correct, eth1 does the job, so i want to have 10.1.1.1 in remote_addr.

Comment: That is really weird , i havent seen a behavior like that , i think this might have something to do with the client network config. If there is routing in place, you might want to check the gateway configuration etc, maybe shut down all connections and bring back one by one and see where the problem starts to happen and then check that specific network adopters config .. just my 2 cents. If both are on seperate subnets than this shouldnt be happening at all, atleast i cant think of a logical reason for it to happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to take all IP information with a grain of salt.

IP addresses are gathered during the request by taking the packet and request information into account. Sadly, this information can easily be spoofed or even be incorrect (based on a large number of network probabilities) and should not be used for anything more than vanity purposes.

Comment: Thx for this one, but is there any best practice you could recommend?

Comment: The code in your question is what I've seen as a "best option". It will catch the correct IP in most cases. Just understand that I wouldn't necessarily trust the results.

Comment: I C and accepted, but could you pls recommend be some reading on how the REMOTE_ADDR etc. are actually set by apache? I'd very much like to understand what's causing me trouble. TIA

Comment: "Sadly, this information can easily be spoofed or even be incorrect " For a TCP based protocol (which HTTP is), it would be interesting for you to explain how easy it is to spoof source IP address. You may be mistaken with the values of it potentially in HTTP headers, which indeed are almost completely under control of the client.