# Xampp: Is localhost port secure?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, localhost

I have been working on  a site for a while so I can get nice and safe before any one else sees it. I use XAMPP to help me with this. I recently noticed something changed  on my site and I didn't make the change. Recently change after change after change. It is a localhost port 80 and I haven't touched it in a while. No one else uses this computer so now I am worried. Is local host secure? I know no one can see it on another computer right? I am worried because I don't want people to hack my private site.

**System Specs:**

> Windows 8
>
> Hp Pavillion Slimline 400
>
> Hp Mouse and Keyboard.
>
> *Xampp newest version.*
>
> Control Panel: *Xampp version 3.2.1*

Comment: XAMP can never be more secure than X. In your case, X == Windows.

Comment: How is it relevant that you use an HP mouse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accepting get/post requests only from localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872751/accepting-get-post-requests-only-from-localhost)

Answer (score 2):

## About XAMPP

Using the default port or not, safety is not only related to xampp, but also its own application.

Therefore port 80, just like any other, is safe since its application and validation are.

There is no such thing as: X port is unsafe and Y port is safe.

## Solutions

You can do that with many ways:

### In you PHP "master" class

```
if (!$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){
  $this->output->set_status_header(400, 'No Remote Access Allowed');
  exit; //just for good measure
}
```

### .htaccess

```
AuthName "bla"  
AuthType Basic  
<Limit GET POST>  
    order deny,allow  
    deny from all 
    allow from 127.0.0.1
    allow from <your-ip-here>
</Limit>
```