# Securing a session-less RESTful API endpoint

Tags: php, api, rest, curl, restful-authentication

I've created a simple RESTful API for a project partially following [this very good blog post by Riyad Kalla](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/). Now, I've read dozens of similar questions on Stack Overflow but I can't seem to find an answer to my security question.

Briefly, my requests go like this:

1. The client has a public API key (plain-text, accessible to anybody sniffing the network traffic or properly checking the code source)
2. The client sends a request to the server with the public API key
3. The server has a secret API key (secret to anybody but the developer)
4. The server creates a HMAC-SHA1 hash composed of the client's request data and the secret API Key
5. The server sends a request identical to the client's request to the API server, but including the resulting HMAC-SHA1
6. The API server looks up the secret API key in its database based on the public API key it receives
7. The API server recreates a HMAC-SHA1 hash using the same data as the developer's server
8. If the hashes match, the request is considered valid and is processed normally

I'm concerned that somebody using my service could fetch the public API key (by sniffing network traffic let's say), and then simply cURL the same request the client would originally do via their browser using AJAX directly to the developer's server. Therefore, the malicious user could be authenticated as a legit user and access the API with somebody else secret API key.

I'll try to give a concrete example. Normally I would do:

1. AJAX a get request to my server.
2. My server hashes my request with my API secret and send it to the API server.
3. The API server validates my request and returns the payload.

But I'm scared that:

1. Dr. Evil will sniff my public API key.
2. Dr. Evil will cURL a get request to my server using my public API key.
3. My server will hash Dr. Evil's request with my API secret and send it to the API server.
4. The API server validates and returns the payload to complete Dr. Evil's vicious plans.
5. Dr. Evil laughs an evil laugh.

Anything I'm missing or is this just part of the RESTful API game?

UPDATE: I am voluntarily omitting any form of timestamp validation to keep things simple and just focus on the authentication issue.

UPDATE 2: I've added a `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` validation to the process. The goal here is that the client must send a referrer along with the request and it must match the referrer listed in the database on the API's side. Unfortunately, HTTP referrers can be faked easily. It is yet another level of security, but still not perfect.

UPDATE 3: I've changed my server side code to set the referrer to the remote IP address. This forces every request sent to my server that wants to be hashed using the secret API key ultimately get to the API server with the original request IP address. This IP can then be validated and the request can go through. I believe it is yet possible to fake `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, but it is more complex than faking `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`... Still not perfect I guess.

**UPDATE 4**: According to these posts: [How to fake $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092563/how-to-fake-serverremote-addr-variable) and https://serverfault.com/questions/90725/are-ip-addresses-trivial-to-forge, faking the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is possible though difficult. It is, however, impossible to receive a response from the faked request since you're not in control of the faked network. The request can be validated successfully but will its response won't fall unto malicious hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've found to stop other scripts from using a public API key and sending requests to the server-side HMAC-hashing script is to send the original requester's *identity* along with the request. I'm using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to determine the original requester's identity since it's harder to fake, and faking it usually means they won't get a response.

```
/* $this as a class that handles requests */

// Build hash and include timestamp
$this->vars['timestamp'] = time();
$this->vars['hash'] = hash_hmac('sha1', http_build_query($this->vars).$this->vars['token'], API_SECRET);

// Send request to API
curl_setopt_array($this->curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => $this->method == 'post' ? 1 : NULL,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $this->method == 'post' ? $this->vars : NULL,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 15,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 15,
    CURLOPT_REFERER => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], // Referer here!
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 3,
    CURLOPT_HTTPGET => $this->method == 'get' ? true : false
));
```

Once sent, the API doesn't only check the secret API key from the database, but it also checks if the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is listed as allowed! This also allows the API to accept servers on a per-user basis.

Answer (score 5):

You are on the right track by using HMAC. However, there are two additional things that will make your application more secure.

1. Require a timestamp in the client POST, needs to validate within 5 min of the server time. It should also be included in HMAC generation. If someone tries to change this the HMAC signature would be invalid, unless they had the secret key to update the HMAC signature.
2. Use SSL, with certificate validation. Prevents a man in the middle attack. Don't allow any non-ssl requests.

Comment: Thanks. I voluntarily excluded the timestamp portion to keep things simple as it's no big deal to implement in my current code, I should've mentioned that. I'm not sure I understand correctly how SSL function. Does it make traffic sniffing impossible? The malicious user can still steal it from the JavaScript source code, no? I'm definitely missing something here...

Comment: SSL is transport encryption. It makes sniffing much more difficult. Even with APIs this is a good idea.

Comment: But I still have the same problem if the malicious user can get the public API key from the source, right?

Comment: The secret key is what matters, as that is used for signing in HMAC. The public key is used as a lookup for the secret on the server side. I'm not quite sure what you mean by your question.

Comment: Here's the situation: malicious user checks the client-side JavaScript and figures out the public API key and the path to the PHP script I'm sending it to hash the request with my secret API key. Malicious user then proceeds to create his or her own PHP script to cURL to my PHP script that hashes request with my secret API key. Malicious user now can send request to his or her PHP script with my public API key, **with his or her data**, which then cURL to my server, hashes with my secret API key, and still validates as *OK* on the API server.

Comment: I think I am missing a bit of your architecture. Are you doing the HMAC authentication client side, in javascript? Or do you have a public php script that accesses the API?

Comment: The HMAC authentication is entirely server-side. But that's exactly my point. Basically, to create the initial HMAC hash, one needs to send the public API key to the server along with some data, correct? This is done with an AJAX call (`$.get('api/some/resource', { public:'hG654hDgLApc' }, [...]);`). What would stop another user to check my JavaScript source code, determine my public key is `hG654hDgLApc`, make a `cURL` request to `api/some/resource` and voilà? I feel like I'm really overthinking this... Thanks for following so far.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22730/discussion-between-datasage-and-remi-breton)