# affect/change superglobals of PHP

Tags: php, superglobals

how can i affect/change a [superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) of PHP? Cause when i enter a website i dont want to give it my IP then i want to affect `HTTP['REMOTE_ADDR']` variable.

**note:** *i know it can be done cause i have seen people who complains how people enter sites with fake IP's via changing PHP globals, but if i know wrong please explain*

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP and should probably be in SuperUser. But if you find a tool to edit any page's PHP let me know (;

Comment: You mean that you want to mask your _client_ IP from servers running PHP code? You will not be able to spoof `REMOTE_ADDR`

Comment: If you want to change PHP superglobals in PHP code you own, you may overwrite them as much as you need. Be careful doing that though -- comment it well.  `$_POST['input_value'] = 'new fake value not from form';` Nothing prevents you from writing to them.

Comment: [This is what is needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092563/how-to-fake-serverremote-addr-variable) if you really wish to spoof REMOTE_ADDR.  It is no trivial task...

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a **server side** langage. You can access **superglobals** by following [this references](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) (**Only** in **PHP page**).

If you are in **client side** (javascript), you **cannot** affect superglobals. Like PHP cannot access your computer variables.