# HTTP_CLIENT_IP not working, REMOTE_ADDR is working, WHY?

Tags: php, web, ip

I am developing a wordpress plugin for geo location.

This is my curiosity question. Why HTTP_CLIENT_IP not showing anything? REMOTE_ADDR shows my ip.

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
echo $ip;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP_CLIENT_IP` is ip from share internet
but `REMOTE_ADDR` is current ip

For Example Function on PHP:

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Comment: Why not just `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`? In which cases would someone was to use the other two?

Comment: It is really easy to [fake the IP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5092951/2205532) if you trust headers over REMOTE_ADDR; which is generally safe.