# How to get web client

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, mac-address

I want to get the web user/client mac address, i.e i want to restrict the users to open my web application with register mac address only. So other systems could not open my web application,
For example, if the user entered URL in the browser and enters, the request will go to the server, in the server side is it possible to capture the mac address of the client?,if it is possible i can restrict him to open my application by checking with my already registered mac addresses.

please help me.

Comment: This is impossible, please read the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454858/how-to-get-client-mac-address-by-a-access-on-a-website

Answer (score 1):

The MAC address does not survive beyond IP routers. You can't find the client MAC address from a remote server.

In a local subnet, the MAC addresses are mapped to IP addresses through the ARP system. You can find the MAC address of computers within your subnet using 'arp -a' or 'nbtstat -A ipaddress' command in windows.
However, when your packets passes though the router from the  local subnet through the gateway out to the  Internet, the originating MAC address is lost.