# Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular5

I am new to Angular ,Here in my project I need to get the MAC address of the user's system .

For that I have executed a NPM as follows

```
npm install --save macaddress
```

Added the below code after the imports in my app.component.ts file

```
var macaddress = require('macaddress');
```

And this in my ngOnInit

```
 macaddress.one(function (err, mac) {
            console.log("Mac address for this host: %s", mac);  
          });
```

After adding all these code and I tried to Serve the project but I got the below error .

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/macaddress/lib/windows.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'D:\Projects\Angular\eCommerceWebsite\node_modules\macaddress\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/macaddress/lib/unix.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'D:\Projects\Angular\eCommerceWebsite\node_modules\macaddress\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/macaddress/lib/linux.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'D:\Projects\Angular\eCommerceWebsite\node_modules\macaddress\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/macaddress/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'D:\Projects\Angular\eCommerceWebsite\node_modules\macaddress'
```

After executed the `npm install --save macaddress` I executed the `npm install -g`

But I can't solve this error ,Can anyone help me to solve this please.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the package **macaddress** makes usage of **child_process** module which is only available in the context of Node.js.

Angular runs in the browser and does not have access to the hardware address as well as the module **child_process**.

Please see the following link for more informations and workarounds:
[How to get client MAC address by a access on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454858/how-to-get-client-mac-address-by-a-access-on-a-website)

Hope this information was helpful.

Regards