# How to deny access for visitors who use proxies?

Tags: php, .htaccess, proxy

So is there any way to block users who use proxies in my web site? Is it possible with PHP or .htaccess? I know that there can't be 100% secure solution, but blocking most of them? Could that be possible? That would be perfect, but i have feeling that it's not so easy.

Thanks

Comment: look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036443/php-how-to-block-proxies-from-my-site

Answer (score 1):

You can try this rule to block all requests from Proxies:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} .+
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

- `HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR` is the header that gets set when requests are coming from a Proxy only.