# How to detect residential proxy

Tags: php, proxy, ip

I would like to know if there are ways to detect residential proxies such as those provided by the proxy provider Luminati.
I did tests to see the different data in the **$_SERVER** variable but I don't see any information that would help me know that.
I would like to know if anyone has a solution to my problem.
I want to **block all users using a proxy**, even those who usurp a residential IP.
Thank you.

Comment: Use a maintained proxy list and block accordingly. These are usually subscription services since maintaining them is a lot of work. I would look into the API services at ipqualityscore.com . They have free tier pricing which should cover most small non-revenue projects.

Comment: Do you this that ipqualityscore.com will be able to detect residential proxies ? Thank you

Comment: I don't know, but they do have a web chat on their site. You can ask them directly. It's just one of many services. If they don't, maybe another one will.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036443/php-how-to-block-proxies-from-my-site Maybe this post will help if you didnt see it already

Comment: @Rustyjim This post will not help me to detect residential proxy sorry.

Comment: You should tell us _why_ you want to do this thing so we can suggest more pertinent options.

Comment: It looks like IP2Proxy is also detecting residential proxies. You might want to check with them and see if it fit your requirements.