# Contact Form IP Address

Tags: php, ip, contacts

I have a contact form, the entire markup for which (other than the javascript) [can be found here.](http://snippi.com/s/ofqj1pc)  The form sends an email with the information input by the user to whichever email is defined under to_email in an options panel.

I am using this form in WordPress and would like to have the IP address of the person filling out the form attached to the message.  I tried incorporating code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687642/how-to-detect-the-visitors-ip-address-using-html) but I'm a newbie to PHP and can't seem to incorporate it correctly (to actually send it with the rest of the message).

If anybody can offer help as to what code  I should include and where I should include it to display the sender's IP address I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments";
```

replace with

```
$body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments \n\nIP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old question, but I though about helping who arrives on this one.
First, I would recommand [Contact form 7 plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) for creating a form with wordpress.

It could look like this at the creation of the form:

[image]

you add in the body of your message (in the screenshot in the right column "Message Body") the following short code :

> [wpcf7.remote_ip]

Your message would (without modification) look like:

> From: [your-name] <[your-email]> Subject: [your-subject]
>
> Message Body: [your-message]
>
> Sent from: [wpcf7.remote_ip]
>
> --
>
> This e-mail was sent from contact form on Testing (heep://localhost:8888/wordpress)

this will print the user IP into the email you'll receive.

Then in your post, you integrate the short code given into the page (like):

> [contact-form-7 id="1056" title="Sample Form"]