# HTML5 geo-location feature for non HTML 5 browser

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I want to get the address of user who is browsing my website. i am doing it with html5 geolocation feature and it is working fine.

But i want to implement this features in browsers which don't supports HTML 5.

Is there any JS library that provides supports to GEOLOCATION api for non html 5 browsers or any workaround to get this done with non html 5 browsers.

Thanks,

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687642/how-to-detect-the-visitors-ip-address-using-html

Comment: There are services that offer geolocation based on IP address. But the accuracy isn't always that great.

Comment: @AyoubAbid that question is about IP address (not geolocation) and doesn't even have an accepted answer.

Comment: @pawel - Ok. but is there any library to suport geolocation for non html 5 browsers.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation