# Setting $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to fake IP address

Tags: php, ip-address

I am mediating requests from client A to server B. Client A may be a phone or a laptop computer. Server B wants to know client A's IP address, but they are looking for it in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. Because I am hitting server B, they are getting the "wrong" value for `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` -- they're getting my servers' IP addresses. What can I do on my side so that server B will see the client's IP address when they access `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` at their endpoint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening at a layer that cannot be overridden by your PHP script. The `X-Forwarded-For` header exists to relay the true client IP, but the remote server must support this easily-spoofed value.

```
$header = "X-Forwarded-For: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}, {$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']}";
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($header));
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it :) - In addition, see here for how server B should detect client A's IP (notice REMOTE_ADDR is the last place you look) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634782/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-to-retrieve-a-users-correct-ip-address-in-php

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Prior answer is perfect. This only applies where your own dev-ip is interfering with client stats.

In the absence of more info, at the most basic level, you should remove your own 'developer IP' so that you're not included in any stats/data/logs...

Your IP may be different to the server in question:

```
<?php 

$dev_ip = '217.12.14.14' // your dev IP address

if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $dev_ip){
    // do nothing
} else {
    // do|show|log something
}
```

This doesn't account for dynamic IP address allocation (rather than a static IP). Dynamic IP's are often allocated by ISPs which is something that causes further issues.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Ahh... So we're talking pass-through of IP to client and acting as a gateway! (sorry, +1 for the comment!)

Comment: Upvote to other answer - entirely correct use of X-forwarded-for, and -1 to me for misreading initial question. I missed the gateway element :)