# Why is fopen() giving me a different IP than $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']?

Tags: php, ip, ip-address, fopen

Using this code:

On server A I have this:

```
$handle = fopen('http://www.server_b.com/get_ip.php', 'r'); //This is just a PHP file that echoes the REMOTE_ADDR
echo "IP looks like ".fread($handle, '100000')." to external server.\n";
fclose($handle);
echo "IP looks like ".$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']." to this server.";
```

on server B I have this:

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

I'm getting the following output from server A:

```
IP looks like xxx.xxx.223.90 to external server. //xxx.xxx on both lines are the same
IP looks like xxx.xxx.223.94 to this server.
```

Why am I getting two different IPs? Note, we do own the IP range from .90-.94

Comment: So, you're getting the IP address of a remote machine, and you're wondering why it's different from the address of the current machine?

Comment: Is "server A" multi-homed, i.e. have multiple network cards?

Comment: Maybe "A" is proxying through the .90 machine?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No, that isn't what I'm doing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a VPS, what you're probably seeing on server_b is the IP address of the host machine of the VPS that server_a is running on.

Either that, or there's some other proxying mechanism going on.

There may be a way around this:

Do a `print_r()` of `$_SERVER` on server_b.

Depending on the config of the various servers involved, in addition to the `REMOTE_ADDR` you may also get a value like `$_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']`. This will be the IP address of the originating machine being passed on by the proxy, and should be the one you're expecting.

This question may help you further: [What is the most accurate way to retrieve a user's correct IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634782/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-to-retrieve-a-users-correct-ip-address-in-php)