# Getting user's full address on internet for transfer

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Is there a way to get a user's full address on the internet, using php, so that the address can be send to a client application on another computer on the internet and enable it to transfer files directly?

What I'm trying to do is:  I have put together a desktop application in vb.net that will exchange live webcam feed between computers on a lan.  However, I want to enable the users to exchange the feed via the internet, but the only servers I will have at my disposal are simple lamp servers.  I'd like to write a script in php that the desktop application can periodically connect to so that the server can confirm the computer's availability as well as maintain it's physical address.  Then, when a computer's desktop webcam app wants to connect to the other, it can check the php server to make sure it's available and grab it's physical address to know where to send the udp packets to.

Also, if anybody has a better suggestion as to how to deal with this need, I'd try anything that might work.  I'm a paramedic at an ambulance service who loves to play with code and my boss is wanting to be able to use our mobile internet connections on our trucks to be able to provide live feed to the local trauma center and interact with trauma surgeons during our transports.  I'm making great progress so far, but this is kind of where I'm stuck.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634782/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-to-retrieve-a-users-correct-ip-address-in-php

Comment: As for what you can do to make this better, I would approach it more like an IRC or Jabber(XMPP) server.  This has join and presence information built in, and you can reuse existing libraries to make implementation easier. Here is one such library: http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/

Comment: There is even a VB.net example: http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/source/browse/trunk/VB.Example/MainForm.vb  This sounds like an awesome project by the way, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [OpenTok](http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/)? Its a javascript based video chatting solution. The service costs money, but is very affordable (free for 25,000 minutes a month)

Comment: I'm in the process of checking out all these links.  Trying to understand some of the code in Jason Sperske's link (thank you, jason!).  I'm definitely interested in the OpenTok.  But, I guess I forgot to mention that this project has a $0.00 budget.  We're a non-profit rural paramedic ambulance service with a very limited yearly budget.  If we can make this work, the trauma center might provide some funding to improve it.  But, as of now, there's no money to work with (which is why I'm only able to use free hosting lamp servers {I like php anyways :) } and visual studio express products).

Comment: As I mentioned, its free for 25,000 minutes a month. Thats >400 hours. As long as the video isn't always on, I doubt you would hit that limit.