# Accurate client IP in PHP

Tags: php, ip-address

I want to match my client IP in PHP. I have stored client IP address in the database IP addresss given by http://www.whatismyip.com/.

while in PHP i used to get client IP Address like this

```
$client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

But both IP Addresses giving are different values.

Is there any way to get correct IP address in PHP

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most accurate way to retrieve a user's correct IP address in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634782/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-to-retrieve-a-users-correct-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: Actually I experienced the same issue, except with whatismyip.org (I would literally go to the `.com` site in one tab and the `.org` site in another tab, and both would display different IP addresses). The only thing I could figure was that either my ISP was proxying me through somewhere else (and one site was able to detect it while the other wasn't able to). I have no idea if that's accurate or not though, but I couldn't come up with anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_ip_address(){
    foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key){
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true){
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip){
                $ip = trim($ip); // just to be safe

                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false){
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` returns the IP address the request originated as seen by the web server. This can be mainly different in the condition when you are accessing the web server from local IP address. Because whatismyip.com returns your public IP and your server will get request from your local IP.

Try to access the page from a remote location and you will get the IP correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing locally... it's obvious there's gonna be different addresses:

- external websites will show you the public one
- internal sites will show you the local one

See [**Public/Private IP ranges**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958825.aspx). Do you recognize the local address in the private ranges?

Once you deploy your project online *(on a server not in your network)*, things will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to detect the proxy server forward IP address if exists.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR']) {
  $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR'];
} else {
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

The PHP codes should be working most of the time now.