# how to get client public ip address using php?

Tags: php

I used

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
{
        //check ip from share internet
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
else if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
{
        //to check ip is pass from proxy
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
else{
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

echo  $ip;
```

to get client ip address

It is working when I test it on my local server but when I upload my files into remote server where i am hosting my web it is fetching my server ip address not client ip

Comment: Is it possible that the client you have tested with is on same machine where your server is? I am using exactly same function and it is giving correct results to me

Comment: I think its already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-php
and here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634782/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-to-retrieve-a-users-correct-ip-address-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server might be behind an internal proxy or a load balancer. Try using my [PHP Utilities Functions](https://github.com/dotancohen/utility-functions) library which has code for this.