# How do I find the IP address of a VPN client in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, ip-address, vpn, pptp

I've been looking around for a while on this issue and after wrestling with my mobile ISP, have finally got a VPN client to test with...

... however ...

All the other solutions using the `$_SERVER` in [this code (great article)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634782/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-to-retrieve-a-users-correct-ip-address-in-php?rq=1) seem to only return the IP address of the VPN server address (192.168.1.sss).

My solution requires me to send a message to a remote machine (on the end of a VPN) and not the main VPN server.

For example:

1. External client browser fills in a form which posts to a PHP page (`VPN:192.168.1.ccc`)
2. The PHP page on server `www.example.com (192.168.1.sss)` then compiles a suite of instructions to send to the remote machine `192.168.1.rrr` on same logical network (through VPN) as server.

... trouble is, $_SERVER[] seems to return 192.168.1.sss rather than 192.168.1.ccc

even if I send a message (using CURL) to 192.168.1.ccc it shows as not found.

any ideas on how to get the VPN client address known to the network in a way that means I can send the message??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK your VPN server would need to act as a pure bridge or fully configured router in order for the whole network to see one another. Sounds like it currently acts as a NAT router or similar limited router. There's not really much PHP can do in this case.

Comment: Thanks @deceze - I was afraid of that. Main reason why I want to hit the device is to respond to a message and wake the device up - a bit like `Wake on LAN` but to do a bit more than that...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to retrieve the original client ip in this case. The client isn't given a separate local address, it's tunneling through the vpn gateway. You may be able to forward traffic back to the client through the gateway, depending on your setup. This [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55791/port-forward-to-vpn-client) has an iptables example.

Comment: Hi @Jeremiah - thanks for great referral to an article. It is almost the exact situation I'm trying for... except the VPN client is a call phone and the 'downstream' device is connected to the WiFi hotspot.

The main reason for all of this VPN thing is that there is no way to hit a cell phone with a message originating from off-network. the mobile providers all block these as not originating 'on network', and being a paired response.

This all works fine on LAN, just not WAN :-(