# Track client IP address and store in SQL table while entering form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have PHP form processing data to sql table i have two input field

- i need a hidden field that hidden field should track client IP address and when form is submitted i need the client address also save in table

### PHP form processing

```
<?php
$db_username = "sanoj";
$db_password = "123456";
try {
#connection 
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=localtest', $db_username, $db_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$data = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO test (first, last) VALUES (:first, :last)');
$first = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'first', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$last = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'last', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$data->execute(array(':first' => $first, ':last' => $last,));
#exception handiling
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

can some one help me i found example and its hard to understand these code given in [What is the most accurate way to retrieve a user's correct IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634782/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-to-retrieve-a-users-correct-ip-address-in-php/2031935#2031935) since new to php 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$REMOTE_ADDR = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];/*add this line*/
$data->execute(array(':first' => $first, ':last' => $last, ':REMOTE_ADDR' => $REMOTE_ADDR));/* edit this line*/
```

Comment: Do you feel better if you first store $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] in a variable instead of using it directly?

Answer (score 1):

I would use this to retrieve someone's IP

```
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```