# Call JS function on 3rd href link clicked from the same IP address

Tags: javascript, html

I have a few .html pages with some `href` links in each.
Please help me with a code to call a JS function on 3rd click from same IP on any of the links.

Example:
IP `111.111.111.111` clicks a link for the 1st time do nothing
IP `111.111.111.111` clicks a link for the 2nd time do nothing
IP `111.111.111.111` clicks a link for the 3rd time `onclick="call_function();"`

To get the `IP` I'll use the code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2031935/4805488

Any help is much appreciated ...

Comment: On each click of a link send an ajax request to the server to get the number of clicked links till now. If the third link is clicked execute the link (don't prevent the default behavior) otherwise stop the default action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below...

Also, if you need this to last over time and switching pages etc., you need to both add an uniqe id to each link and then store it in a cookie or server side, based on how important it is with exactly 3 clicks per link.

Having the "data-clicked" added to a link, you can have other links which will not act in the same way.

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  
    if (e.target.getAttribute("data-clicked") == undefined) { return true; };
    
    var clk = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute("data-clicked"));
  
    if (clk >= 2) {
      e.target.setAttribute('data-clicked', 0);
      
      alert("Clicked 3 times");
      
    } else {
      e.target.setAttribute('data-clicked', clk + 1);
      
    }
  
    e.preventDefault();
  
    return false;
  
});
```

```html
<a href='http://stackoverflow.com/' data-clicked='0'> Click me 3 times </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas so you can achieve this:

- use [Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) to increment a value for each visit (here is an example I wrote for your case that shows an alert after 3 clicks: http://jsbin.com/mamebeyiye/edit?html,js,output)
- store this information in a [cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)
- you could also manage this on the server side, but that's another story and probably more difficult

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies) can help you decide which solution is best between cookies and local storage.

Comment: This is, at best, a comment.

Comment: Your answer was a bunch of links.

Comment: I try to answer questions with the same quantity of details the question provides. From the question, I understand that @Brooks doesn't know where to start so I'm giving hints. I'm not going to write code for him if I don't know his requirements better.

Comment: Thanks @LGSon. Just did. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a onclick="call_function(this, alertMe);">click me</a>
```

You can do something like:

```
function call_function(element, callback) {
   //check to see if clicked before or else start with 0;
   var clicked = parseInt(element.getAttribute('data-clicked') || 0);
   // increment the amount of clicks
   clicked++;
   // store the click amount in a data attribute
   element.setAttribute('data-clicked', clicked);
   // return the callback when the click amount 3 or greater. 
   return clicked >= 3 ? callback() : false;
}

function alertMe() {
   alert('wow! 3 times is....')
}
```

alternatively you can use localStorage.setItem() and localStore.getItem() instead of setAttribute and getAttribute if you want the clicked number to persist over time (until localStorage is cleared again)

Comment: Try avoid adding handlers inline. It will make maintenance so much easier and html code so much cleaner.