# How to trace the user's country using ip address he is using?

Tags: ip, ip-address

i want to know how to trace someone accessing my website using his/her ip-address.
because if there's a code then i want it to insert in my website to deny the users from some countries to access my website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most accurate way to retrieve a user's correct IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634782/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-to-retrieve-a-users-correct-ip-address-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the API mentioned below to get ip address details.
This API is free.
https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/8.8.8.8

Where 8.8.8.8 is the ip address and you can replace it according to your user IP address.
It will result like

> {"ip":"8.8.8.8","country":"United States","country_code":"US","city":null,"continent":"North America","latitude":37.751,"longitude":-97.822,"time_zone":"America/Chicago","postal_code":null,"org":"Google LLC","asn":"AS15169","subdivision":null,"subdivision2":null}

Comment: can i use this in my website to trace someone that is using some of the countries i don't want to access my website?

Comment: Yes you can use it, use it on server side like, get ip address of user and restrict if necessary.